# Requirements.txt is not packed in the model.tar.gz using Sagemaker Pytorch Estimator

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint, inference, requirements.txt

I'm using SageMaker Pipeline workflow to train a model and register it. Then later I'll create an endpoint from the registered model.

I need to install some python packages in my inference.py file, such as gensim. I put a requirements.txt file in the same folder as train.py and inference.py.

**The problem is that the requirements.txt is not being packed in the model.tar.gz.** That's why although the training and creating the endpoint work fine, but when I check the loggings of the deployed endpoint I see the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'
```

This is a part of my script for training and registering the model.

```
from sagemaker.pytorch.estimator import PyTorch
from sagemaker.workflow.step_collections import RegisterModel
from sagemaker.workflow.steps import (
    ProcessingStep,
    TrainingStep,
)

    train_estimator = PyTorch(entry_point= 'train.py',
                                source_dir= BASE_DIR,
                                instance_type= "ml.m5.2xlarge",
                                instance_count=1,
                                role=role,
                                framework_version='1.8.0',
                                py_version='py3',
                                )
    step_train = TrainingStep(
        name="TrainStep",
        estimator=train_estimator,
        inputs={
                "train": sagemaker.TrainingInput(
                            s3_data=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs[
                            "train_data"
                            ].S3Output.S3Uri,
                            content_type= 'text/csv',
                        ),
        },
    )
    step_register = RegisterModel(
        name="RegisterStep",
        estimator= train_estimator,
        model_data=step_train.properties.ModelArtifacts.S3ModelArtifacts,
        content_types=["application/json"],
        response_types=["application/json"],
        inference_instances=["ml.t2.medium", "ml.m5.2xlarge"],
        transform_instances=["ml.m5.large"],
        model_package_group_name=model_package_group_name,
        approval_status=model_approval_status,
        source_dir = BASE_DIR,
        entry_point= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "inference.py"),
        depends_on = [step_train]
    )
```

This is the structure of my files:

```
-abalone
  - __init__.py
  - train.py
  - inference.py
  - requirements.py
  - preprocess.py
  - evaluate.py
  - pipeline.py
```

BASE_DIR refers to abalone folder.

In the model.tar.gz I see:

```
- model.pth
- model.pth.wv.vectors_ngrams.npy
- code
  - __pycache__
  - train.py
  - _repack_model.py
  - inference.py
  - preprocess.py
  - evaluate.py
  - __init__.py
  - pipeline.py
```

You can see that it contains everything except the requirements.txt file.

In the sagemaker [documents](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/v2.25.2/frameworks/pytorch/using_pytorch.html?highlight=requirements.txt) it says:

"The PyTorch and PyTorchModel classes repack model.tar.gz to include the inference script (and related files), as long as the framework_version is set to 1.2 or higher."

But you can see although my framework_version is higher than 1.2, but still it doesn't pack requirements.txt file in the model.tar.gz.

Can someone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: this link could be useful https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/2759

Comment: I'm not able to recreate this issue @user_5. I created a pipeline with a TrainingStep using a PyTorch estimator and a RegisterModel step. In my BASE_DIR I added a requirements.txt file. The model tarball ends up with all of the files in BASE_DIR, including requirements.txt.

Comment: One thing to note is that pipelines, not the PyTorch container, is doing the repacking via a training job. You should see a training job with "RegisterStep" in its name that runs [_repack_model.py](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/dev/src/sagemaker/workflow/_repack_model.py). 

I would check the CloudWatch logs for that job and see if anything pops out. This is just speculation but it's possible the training container has a lock on the requirements.txt file which is preventing it from being copied to the output directory.

Comment: @Payton, Thanks a lot for you effort. Could you send me the configuration or the versions of the Pytorch, Python and Sagemaker you used?

Comment: @Payton, In the Register loggings I didn't find anything helpful. It only says that the dependencies are empty: /miniconda3/bin/python _repack_model.py --dependencies  --inference_script inference.py --model_archive model.tar.gz --source_dir /root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/...

Comment: @Payton, also please consider that I'm creating this pipeline not in the Sagemaker SDK, but in a template of Sagemaker Studio and it actually creates CloudFormation and CodePipeline pipelines and then runs this. I think this might also be effective.

Comment: SageMaker SDK version: 2.72.1, Python version 3.6.13, Pytorch version 1.5.0

That the pipeline is being created with a project template shouldn't make a difference; your CodeCommit repository has a `pipeline.py` file which is generating the pipeline definition with the SDK; whether the pipeline is created via an SDK call or by CloudFormation should be immaterial. 

You may want to check that the requirements.txt file is being uploaded to S3. You'll find that S3 path in the `sagemaker_submit_directory` hyperparameter in the training job doing the model repacking.

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot you have requirements.py instead of requirements.txt in your base folder

Answer (score 0):

A workaround can be by installing the required packages in the `inference.py` using

```
import os 
os.execute("pip install package1 package2 ...")
```

To troubleshoot the issue, I'd recommend deploying the estimator `train_estimator` using `train_estimator.deploy` which will create the model, endpoint configuration and the endpoint. Then, check CloudWatch logs to see if it's still failing to pack `requirements.txt`.

The `requirements.txt` might be used as an environment variable attached with the model created by `estimator.deploy` and because you use `RegisterModel`, it ignores that parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I've used the os.system(..) to install the packages in the inference.py , but I'd like to fix the issue with packing the requirement.txt